# Audio Comparion in iPhone 4g

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to ask that, Is it possible to compare two audio files in iphone? Does objective-c have any framework for audio comparison?

please help me out on this, I want to compare different audio files with one another.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the kind of audio comparison? You can test the contents of two files for binary equality, but I'm not sure of anything higher-level.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to compare?  The files lengths?  Whether 2 songs are in the same key?  Or what?

Answer (score 0):

In `Iphone` no framework is available to compare the two audio files . 
You should take the two array of sample data and compare as integer or float value. and set the threshold value (if 70 % ) frames matched so voice is same .